# How to change default folder structure of ASP.NET Core app that uses Individual Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an Asp.Net Core web app and use the option Individual Authentication. The auto-generated code was structured like the picture bellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tne9y.png)

[image]

I don't want the `XxxViewModels` (e.g. `AccountViewModels`) folders inside Models folder, but in a folder named `ViewModels` that is parallel with the `Models` folder. How I can achieve while that assuring that all the namespaces are still consistent with the new structure without having to manually change them?

Comment: I guess you  can change this class location without changing its namespace. But it wont be a nice idea. I would change the location and the namespace too. It's easy to find the erros, because it will throw an compilation error.

Comment: yes. I want the namespaces to be consistent with the folder structure so that it will be easier to maintain when the project grows. I found a solution which is using Ctr + R + R. However, it only allows me to change 1 level at a time. I still need to manually adjust in some locations